# Affine transformation to transform a plane into another

Tags: computational-geometry

Having the implicit plane equation

$$ax + by + cz + d = 0\,,$$

how do I find the affine transformation that must be applied to transform this plane into the plane with equation

$$x + y = 0\,?$$

Please note in my case this is the *horizontal* plane as $y$ points up.

Comment: "How do I code this?" is off-topic, here, so I've removed that part of your question.

Comment: Sounds like a pure math question to me.  What do other community members feel -- migrate to Math.SE, or leave it here?

Comment: @D.W. Without the programming aspect, I agree that only mathematics remains: it's now non-computational geometry.

Comment: But isn't all of math contained within computer science? Proofs are programs, etc etc :)

Comment: @user63024, see http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/704/755 and http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/260/755.  The short answer is: pure math questions aren't necessarily off-topic here, if they're best answered from a CS perspective, but we expect the question to explain why they need to be answered from a CS perspective.

Comment: I appreciate moderation but I'm nor sure it was a good idea to change the last part of my question to "how do I code this?" and then get rid of it but maybe I wasn't clear enough that I am after an explanation that maps easily to code. Pseudocode is fine. Should I re-edit in this sense?